# Convert JSON string into meaning full data to parse

Tags: c#, javascript, sql, regex

ok so i have this string:

```
[{"id":1},{"id":2,"children":[{"id":3},{"id":4,"children":[{"id":5,"children":[{"id":6}]}]},{"id":7}]}]
```

I would like to be able to parse it and use it as a meaningful data to enter into my database.

output after parsing, as an array/ or you can suggest a different ouput if you think it is better to extract the data from. this is just my idea.

```
[0]  id:1
[1]  id:2 -> id:3, id:4 -> id:5 -> id:6
[2]  id:7
```

is this even possible with regex

to give you a better understanding, why I am asking you this. I have a tree structure 
here:

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/UXIpAHU/3/edit

I would like to be able to parse the output and save that into a sql database, with 2 columns

ID column contains all ids for all the items, but only ids that are children or have a parent will have a parentID. so the sql table would look like this based on the DEMO:

```
ID | ParentID
------------------------
1     NULL
2     NULL
3      2
4      2
5      4
6      5
7      2
```

what is the best way to achieve this, I am kinda looking for some ideas/solution for my problem. thank you.

Comment: can this string be parsed as a JSON object to get the data i want?

Comment: not without modifying it a bit - what is `->` supposed to mean, and where does its scope end?

Comment: if you look at my demo link in the question and look at the function  CreateSerOutput() I am creating the string in there, it can be modified if you wish to be able to support JSON? but i am not very familiar with how JSON works so...

Comment: @PinnyM I have updated my code in the DEMO url:  http://jsbin.com/UXIpAHU/3/edit , according to JSON standards up to my knowledge, as well as the string in my question to support JSON. will the new format work for JSON?

Comment: Be wary of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/191410) when asking questions. It is best not to conflate your goal with your knee-jerk-solution. First explain your context and what you want to accomplish - this is the meat of your question. Then explain what you've tried so far or what you are thinking of trying - this is helpful to answerers, but is not part of the core question. Regex was never really relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP changed the question, so the following is based on previous question:

If you control the output, then you should use XML as your transfer language.  It is VERY simple to use and there is built in support in C# for it.

Your result go from this:

```
{"id":1},{"id":2->"children":{"id":3},{"id":4->"children":{"id":5->"children":{"id":6}}},{"id":7}}
```

Would become:

```
<root>
    <item id="1" />
    <item id="2">
        <item id="3" />
        <item id="4">
            <item id="5">
                <item id="6" />
            </item>
        </item>
        <item id="7" />
    </item>
</root>
```

Then you can read it with:

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse(xml); // or .Load(file)
Dictionary<int,int?> list = root.Descendants("item")
    .ToDictionary(x => (int)x.Attribute("id"), x => 
    {
        var parentId = x.Parent.Attribute("id");
        if (parentId == null)
            return null;
        return (int)parentId;
    });
```

Now you have a dictionary list of key value pairs just as you wanted with

```
ID | ParentID
------------------------
1     NULL
2     NULL
3      2
4      2
5      4
6      5
7      2
```

**=== Convert Back ===**

```
Dictionary<int, int?> dic = new Dictionary<int, int?>
{
    {1,null},
    {2,null},
    {3,2},
    {4,2},
    {5,4},
    {6,5},
    {7,2}
};

XElement root = new XElement("root");
foreach (var kvp in dic)
{
    XElement node = new XElement("item", new XAttribute("id", kvp.Key));

    int? parentId = kvp.Value;
    if (null == parentId)
        root.Add(node);
    else
    {
        // Get first item with id of parentId
        XElement parent = root.Descendants("item")
            .FirstOrDefault(i => (int)i.Attribute("id") == (int)parentId);
        if (null != parent) // which it shouldn't for our array
            parent.Add(node);
    }
}
```

To get to a string, use:

```
string xml = root.ToString();
```

Or to save to a file:

```
root.Save("filepath");
```

Comment: Any reason why JSON shouldn't be used as the transfer protocol?  After all, it's already there, and is also well supported...

Comment: @PinnyM No reason it can't be.  I just find XML easy to use.

Comment: @PinnyM do you have a way for me to parse my string using JSON to extract the data, as that would require no code changes to my existing functionality.

Comment: @PrakashChennupati If you end up writing the XML, here is a guide to doing so with Javascript: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12504/Writing-XML-using-JavaScript

Comment: @ChuckSavage ah cool, I will try it out and see if the XML version helps me out

Comment: @PrakashChennupati: sure, use the [Json.NET package](http://json.codeplex.com/) now MS supported

Comment: @PrakashChennupati Reading some of the comments on the previous link, makes me think that package might not work, but here's another: http://oreilly.com/pub/h/2127

Comment: Cool it works, one more thing. is it possible to convert that list back into the xml? how do i do that?

Comment: also is it possible to use Guid instead of int?

Comment: @PrakashChennupati I added a convert back to the answer.  I don't know what you mean by guid.  You should ask as a separate question perhaps.

Comment: @PrakashChennupati You can use any value as the parentId if that is what you are saying.  Just cast it to that value.  You'd also have to declare the Dictionary to be of that type for the key-value-pair.

Answer (score 1):

You could just deserialize it into a class and easely extract the data from there.

Note that System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer is in System.Web.Extensions

```
[Serializable()]
public class Info
{
 private int _id;

 private List<Info> _children;
 public int Id {
  get { return _id; }
  set { _id = value; }
 }

 public List<Info> Children {
  get { return _children; }
  set { _children = value; }
 }

}


public void Main()
{
 string json = null;
 List<Info> result = null;
 System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer ser = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

 json = "[{\"id\":1},{\"id\":2,\"children\":[{\"id\":3},{\"id\":4,\"children\":[{\"id\":5,\"children\":[{\"id\":6}]}]},{\"id\":7}]}]";

 result = ser.Deserialize<List<Info>>(json);

 foreach (Info p in result) {
  Console.WriteLine(p.Id);

  if (p.Children != null) {
   foreach (Info c in p.Children) {
    Console.WriteLine("   " + c.Id);
   }
  }
 }

 Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Comment: @PrakashChennupati a GUID is just a string

Comment: so i changed return type to string, but i am getting an error when i use Deserialize saying Cannot convert type system.string to type system.Collections.Generic.List this is my string json = "[{\"id\":21a6022f-ee6d-458f-9d6d-53e655ea5200},{\"id\":c2145bb7-f753-412f-a950-4d31c4dd2de3},{\"id\":0660b2e6-df96-4090-b087-c7c67fd8dddb},{\"id\":0b129f2f-32ef-4094-9940-e040efb45b06}]"

Comment: Your json looks wrong, GUID is not a standard type, it has to be in quotes. Also, instead of string you can always use System.GUID

Answer (score 1):

Using [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/), you can simply pass your string in to get a JArray of JObjects:

```
JArray arr = JArray.Parse(yourString)
```

You can then use LINQ as you would on any LINQ-supporting collection.