# read XML, save it into dictionary with multiple values

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary

ok so i have the following XML:

```
<root>
    <item id="1" level="1" />
    <item id="2" level="1">
        <item id="3" level="2"/>
        <item id="4" level="2">
            <item id="5" level="3">
                <item id="6" level="4" />
            </item>
        </item>
        <item id="7" level="2" />
    </item>
</root>
```

i would like to get the dictionary output to be like this, so that way i can insert the data into my sql database,

```
ID | ParentID  | level
------------------------
1     NULL         1
2     NULL         1
3      2           2
4      2           2
5      4           3
6      5           4
7      2           2
```

currrently this my code to get the first 2 columns, but not sure how to get the 3rd column "level" to show up in my dictionary.

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse(strSerializedoutput);
Dictionary<int, int> list = root.Descendants("item").ToDictionary(x => (int)x.Attribute("id"), x =>
    {
        var parentId = x.Parent.Attribute("id");
        if (parentId == null)
            return 0;
        return (int)parentId;
    });
```

Comment: Use a `DataTable` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) not a dictionary.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, you use use a `DataTable`, buuut you could also potentially use an anonymous type as well:

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse(strSerializedoutput);
var list = root.Descendants("item")
    .ToDictionary(x => (int)x.Attribute("id"), x =>
    {
        var parentId = (int)x.Parent.Attribute("id");
        var level = (int)x.Parent.Attribute("level");

        return new { ParentID = parentId, Level = level };
    });
```

So for example, when you finally write to the DB, you'd use `list.ParentID` and `list.Level`.

Comment: when i try your method, i am getting an argumentNullexception saying value cannot be null for var parentID = (int)x.parent.attribute("id");

Comment: @PrakashChennupati Seriously Prakash copy the code I gave you before for determining the parentId here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19184376/353147  You are expecting NULL's for some of the parent id's, so why does it surprise you that you are getting some?

Comment: @ChuckSavage I tired with you code, but I have another attribute level now i want to use, as shown above, but the dictionary only takes max 2 levels...

Comment: @PrakashChennupati So create a class that takes the int? and the new value.  And put that class in the dictionary as the Value.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  y.targetelement, y.[Columns], y.[ColumnsAsXml],
        y.ColumnsAsXml.value('(item/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS COLUMN_1,
        y.ColumnsAsXml.value('(item/text())[2]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS COLUMN_2,
        y.ColumnsAsXml.value('(item/text())[3]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS COLUMN_3,
        y.ColumnsAsXml.value('(item/text())[4]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS COLUMN_4
FROM
(
    SELECT  x.*, CONVERT(XML, N'<item>' + REPLACE(x.[Columns], N'->', N'</item> <item>') + N'</item>') AS ColumnsAsXml
    FROM    
    (
        SELECT 'TEST1', NULL UNION ALL
        SELECT 'TEST2', NULL UNION ALL
        SELECT 'TEST3', 'TEST2->TEST3' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'TEST4', 'TEST2->TEST4' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'TEST7', 'TEST2->TEST7' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'TEST6', 'TEST2->TEST4->TEST5->TEST6' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'TEST5', 'TEST2->TEST4->TEST5'   
    ) x(targetelement, [Columns])
) y
```